# iPhone iOS how to create a room for an iPhone game demo?

Tags: iphone, ios5, opengl-es, uikit, core-motion

I'm building an iPhone core motion game demo and would like to have a virtual "room" around the user. The user would be using the phone with the core motion to "look around" the room through the phone. Attached is an example.

I'm not looking for anything fancy. 4 solid color panels for walls and 2 panels for the floor and ceiling would do. Pretty much a large cube with the middle at the user's location

**What is the quickest way for me to create a room with a box geometry, putting the user in the middle? Can this be done with UIKit objects, or do I need to use openGL to render the panels?** Maybe there's some kind of a game engine that I can use for these purposes?

I would want to rotate the room in the future.

Thank you for your input!

[image: Wolfteinstein]

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to create a 3 dimensional environment without using OpenGL in some form.  The best way to get started is to follow a good tutorial on OpenGL such as [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial). You could even take this tutorial and put the camera inside the cube and voila, instant room. You would just need to add view rotation logic from core motion and you would be set.